# Artinian ring with unbounded descending chain length

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The ascending chain condition does not imply the existence of an integer $n$ such that all ascending chains stop after $n$ steps. For a simple example consider $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a nice example of this for the descending chain condition?

Comment: Each Artinian ring is also Noetherian, by a theorem of Hopkins, so has finite length as a module over itself.

Answer (score 1):

A theorem of Hopkins states that each left Artinian unital ring $R$ is also
left Noetherian. So $R$ as a left $R$-module satisfies both chain conditions,
and so has finite length $m$: it has a composition series (with finitely
many terms). By the Jordan-Holder theorem, every composition series has length $m$
and every chain of left ideals in $I$ can be refined to a composition series,
and so has length $\le m$.

Of course the same is true for right ideals if $R$ is right Artinian,
and if $R$ is commutative, the proofs are a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to convert!